# $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ strictly monotone function $\lim f(x) = 0$, but $\lim f^\prime(x) \ne 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist  a strictly monotone function $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = 0$, but

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f^\prime(x)  $$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} f^\prime(x)$  do not exist?

---

en, counterexamples can  be found, according to ['Obvious' theorems that are actually false](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820686/obvious-theorems-that-are-actually-false/820760#820760)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $\phi:\R \to \R$ be a smooth, non-negative function having a thin "bump" of height $1$ near each integer, and such that the bumps have finite total area. Define
$$
g(x) = \phi(x) + \frac{1}{1 + x^{2}},\qquad
f(x) = -\int_{x}^{\infty} g(t)\, dt.
$$
Since $g = f'$ is smooth and strictly positive, $f$ is strictly increasing. By construction, $g(x) = f'(x)$ has no limit as $x \to \infty$