# Examples of real world situations where mathemematical rigour is needed

Tags: soft-question

I had a discussion with a friend about the need  of mathematical rigour in the real world. He argues that little rigour is needed for the "application  of mathematical results.Mathemticiians complicate 'obvious facts'. I don't agree with the idea that being obvious makes something true. For instance [BanachTarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox), [0.999...=1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...),etc but all of such examples come from purely mathematical point of view and have no real world applications. This makes me wonder if there is a need of mathematical rigour  in the real worl situations?

Comment: Well, most of mathematics isn't concerned with the "real world," in the sense of applications that companies will pay you for. Ditto even for physics, if you restrict the "real world" to classical Newtonian mechanics. What sorts of applications do you have in mind?  As for ostensibly obvious things that are actually false, here's a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820686/obvious-theorems-that-are-actually-false .

Comment: I had a tutor at university once who often expressed genuine fear that the nearby nuclear power station would blow up because a mathematician employed there would find a solution to an differential equation and not ask if it was the.... *only* one!!!

Comment: A level of rigour is definitely required for applying statistical results to the real world. You could get an idea of this at the cross validated site....

Comment: @Frank nice example

Comment: Did he give an example in which "*little rigour* is needed"? Could you tell us some situation that your friend don't agree that rigour is needed?

Comment: What would it mean to say that little (or much) rigor is needed in the *application* of mathematical results to the real world?  The word "rigor" is usually applied to doing mathematics rather than to applying it, I think.  One could argue that rigor is needed in doing mathematics, even applied mathematics, in order to end up with something that applies in all situations rather than just the few particular situations that inspired the research.  Otherwise one would have to worry that the non-rigorous reasoning that was good enough for one application might not be good enough for the next.