# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1+\sin(n))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I think it doesn't exists but I can't find out how to prove it; note that $n$ is integer.

I know that there are infinite many integers $a_n$ s.t. $\sin(a_n)>0$ and then limsup is $+ \infty$.

I want to prove that liminf $\ne +\infty$ but I don't know how.

Comment: How efficiently can you approximate $\pi$ with rationals?

Comment: I know that there are sequences of integers s.t. $|p_m - \pi q_m| < 1/q_m$

Comment: You want to show the $\lim\sup$ is different than $\lim\inf$.  Think about subsequences of the naturals where $\sin$ is very close to $1$, and where $\sin$ is very close to $-1$.

Comment: @SteveD he knows that, the actual proof is the difficult part.

Comment: @Mickey: The fact "he knows that" was not evident from the question at the time of my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. We are going to prove it the hard way.

1. $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}n(\sin n +1 ) = +\infty$

   If one make a plot of $\max( \sin(x),\sin(x+3) )$ over $[0,2\pi]$, one will notice it is bounded from below by $-2\cos(1.5) \approx -0.0707372$.
   For any $n$, at least one of $\sin n + 1$ or $\sin(n+3) + 1$ will be greater than $0.9$. As a result
   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} n(\sin n+1) \ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} 0.9n = \infty$$
2. $\liminf_\limits{n\to\infty} n(\sin n+1) = 0$.

   We will use a theorem by Minkowski,

   > Given any $\theta \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}$ such that
   >   $x - \theta y - \alpha = 0$ has no integer solutions.
   >   For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists infinitely many pairs of integers $p,q$ such that 
   >   $$|q(p - \theta q - \alpha)| < \frac14\quad\text{ and }\quad |p - \theta q - \alpha| < \epsilon$$

   Apply this to $\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $\alpha = -\frac34$, there are infinitely many pairs of non-zero $p,q$ such that
   $$\left|q - 2\pi\left(p+\frac34\right)\right| < \frac{\pi}{2|q|}$$
   If $q$ is positive, let $n = q, m = p$. If $q$ is negative, let $n = -3q$ and $m = -3(p+1)$.
   Above inequality reduces to
   $$\left|n - 2\pi\left(m + \frac34\right)\right| < \frac{\pi}{2n} \times
   \begin{cases}1, & q > 0\\ 9, & q < 0\end{cases}$$
   Together with another easy to verify inequality, 
   $$0 \le \sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\theta\right) + 1 \le \frac{\theta^2}{2}$$
   we obtain infinitely many positive $n$ such that
   $$0 \le n(\sin(n) + 1) \le \frac{81\pi^2}{8n}$$
   This implies $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} n(\sin n+1) \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{81\pi^2}{8n} = 0$$
   Since that limit inferior has to be non-negative, it has to be zero.

Combine $1)$ and $2)$, we can conclude $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sin n + 1)\;$ doesn't exist.

**Notes**

About this particular theorem (Minkowski has tons of theorems), 
Minkowski first proved it around $1901$ using some geometrical methods he invented. Nowadays, those methods are known as [Geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers). Look at any
book under this subject, you should find a proof of that.

I learned this stuff from a book [The Geometry of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856433) by Olds, Lax and Davidoff's. It is easy to read and has a proof at Chapter 10.
Another proof can be found at Chapter 2 of Ivan Niven's classic [Diophantine Approximations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486462676).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can find a proof of Minkowsky theorem?

Comment: @Bremen000 I updated my answer with some refs.

Comment: @achillehui Can you take a look at my answer and see whether it is true or not ?

Comment: For 1. all you need to notice is that $\sin n > 0$ for infinitely many $n.$ I'm not sure why you're going through all that for this part.

Comment: @zhw [being obvious does not imply that it's true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820686/obvious-theorems-that-are-actually-false). Let's say it is obvious but not so "obvious" to the point that it must be true.

Comment: The sequence $1,2,3,\dots$ lands in each of $(0,\pi), (2\pi,3\pi), (4\pi,5\pi),\dots,$ which gives $\sin n > 0$ for infinitely many $n.$

Comment: What do you think about  $\mathsf{my\ answer}$ ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin the proof itself is fine. However, OP also want to rule out the case $L$ exists as $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll think about some modification. I just wanted to know a mathematician opinion.

Comment: @FelixMarin I'm not a mathematician. I'm just an amateur.

Comment: @achillehui what if I put $n^p(1+\sin(n))$ with $p \ge 3$? Can we use a similar technique?

Comment: @Bremen000 No, we can't. We don't know what is the value of $\mu(\pi)$ ( the [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) for $\pi$ ). We just know $2 \le \mu(\pi) < 7.6063$. If we know the value of $\mu(\pi)$, depends on whether $p$ is less than or greater than $2(\mu(\pi)-1)$, it might be possible to show $\liminf_{n\to\infty} n^p(1+\sin(n)) = 0$ or $+\infty$ using a similar technique....

Answer (score 0):

consider $$u_n=v_n.w_n $$ with $\lim v_n=+\infty $ and $\lim w_n $ doesn't exist, so to compute $\lim u_n $, we get an ideterminate form.

$$\{\sin (n),n\in\mathbb N\} $$ is dense in $[-1,1] $ .

Comment: You haven't disproved that the limit is $\infty.$

Comment: @zhw. Ok. i will edit it now.

Comment: I already knew that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n)$ doesn't exists but i do not understand how "we conclude..."